# How to capture a value 3 components deep in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have three components in my angular application, A, B and C.
A is the main component, B is a smaller section that is nested inside A and C is a modal dialog.

The template code for component A looks something like this...

```
<main>
   <h1>Component body title</h1>
   <app-component-b></app-component-b>
   <button (click)="openModal()">Open</button>
</main>
```

Component A ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { ComponentC } from '../component-c/component-c.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-a'
})

export class ComponentA {
  public data;
  public form-data;

  constructor (private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  public openModal() {
     const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ComponentC, {
        height: '100%',
        data: this.data
     });

     dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        this.form-data = result;
     });
  }
}
```

From component A, you can open the modal dialog i.e Component C. Inside the modal dialog, there is a form that you fill in and when you submit, the `form.value` gets passed into the MatDialog's `close()` method, which returns an observable that I am subscribing to in component A - `dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(...)`

Here is the part that trips me up. I need to be able to call a method inside component B (the one nested in component A), once the modal dialog is closed and the data from the modal has been received in component A. I need to pass that form-data into a method in Component B. The problem is that when the page loads initially, form-data is undefined. I figure I could do this via a combination of @Output decorator and some custom event binding but I can't quite figure it out.

How do I make is so that, when the modal dialog is closed and the data is passed back to component A, the nested component B can call a method and pass that data in?

Comment: First solution would be services. You have a modalService which you can use in `ComponentA` and `CombonentB`. It has a shared observable which you subscribe to in `ComponentB` and then run your code which depends on the data.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing @Input in component-b

app-component-a.html

```
<app-component-b [data]="form-data"></app-component-b>
```

app-component-b.ts

```
@Input() data; // Here will be the data
```

So after you close the dialog and recieve the data you need to pass it down to the component-b. Since component-b is component-as child you need to use @Input decorator in the component-b. Output would be used if you need to pass the data to the parent component ( from component-b to component-a )

Comment: `@Input()` would indeed get me the `form-data` value but the problem is that I need to call a method immediately that value is received. `form-data` is just a param I need to pass to my method.